# Flutter multi webview at the same screen with scroll

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, webview

I have a problem when I am trying to fit a web view in containers with scroll and I need to make the height of the container fits the whole HTML page as will the other containers where the real problem is I should give every single container a height to make the scroll action works fine and I don't really know how much the height of the webview will be because in our case the height will be different every time and here is my code down there.

```html
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var dwidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    var dheight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
  body: SafeArea(
    child: ListView.builder(
        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
        itemCount: 5,
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
          return Container(
            child: WebView(
              javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
              onWebViewCreated: (controller) {
                this.controller = controller;
                loadHtml();
              },
            ),
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: tertiaryColor,
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
            ),
          );
        }),
  ),
  backgroundColor: mainColor,
);
  }
```